# 2 processes running on Sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Using Rails 3.2 and Thinking Sphinx 3.0.6. When I checked the processes running on my production environment, I got this:

```
deployer@vps:~$ ps aux | grep search
deployer   401  0.0  0.0 102340  1588 ?        S    10:38   0:00 searchd --pidfile --config /home/deployer/abc/releases/1/config/production.sphinx.conf
deployer   402 47.0  0.7 248984 29944 ?        Sl   10:38   0:12 searchd --pidfile --config /home/deployer/abc/releases/1/config/production.sphinx.conf
```

There are 2 processes in Sphinx. Is this behavior right?

Everytime when I run `ts:stop`, it hangs, and I have to kill one of the processes manually to stop Sphinx. I'm not sure if this is caused by the two processes.

**Update 1**

My `thinking_sphinx.yml`:

```
production:
  pid_file: /home/deployer/abc/shared/pids/searchd.pid
  indices_location: /home/deployer/abc/shared/db/sphinx
  searchd_file_path: /home/deployer/abc/shared/db/sphinx
  config_file: /home/deployer/abc/shared/config/production.sphinx.conf
  mysql41: 9312
  mem_limit: 512M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two processes is normal - TS v3 uses Sphinx's threaded workers (so, you're seeing the master process and at least one child).

As for the ts:stop issue - I presume this is via Capistrano? It's probably because the configuration file doesn't exist for the current deployed release. You should probably change the file location (using the configuration_file setting) to somewhere in the shared directory.

This is covered in [the deployment documentation](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/deployment.html) (but was only added about a month ago).

As for the yml settings - you can remove `searchd_file_path`, as it's been replaced by `indices_location` in TS v3, and `config_file` should be `configuration_file`.

Comment: `ts:stop` freezes while done direct in live server, not via Capistrano.

Comment: Right - but does the configuration file exist where it should? Capistrano's just calling ts:stop as well.

Comment: You are right, missing `.conf` file. Please see my `thinking_sphinx.yml` in the question. When I run `rake ts:configure RAILS_ENV=production`, it generates the `.conf` in the `current` path, but not `shared`. Why is it so?

Comment: See the update to my answer - your settings aren't quite right.